# How to get the hitted area after hitTestObject(Actionscript)

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

for example if two object(one - circle, second - square) are hitted, how can I get the hitted area in pixels, and then for example draw that area to some other color?

ps: I found something like object.hitArea - but how to use it in this case?

Comment: Do you mean that when two objects intersect you want to change the colour of the overlapping portions of those objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hitArea property is for defining a region of your sprite that is clickable, not the area that was overlapped in a hit test.

To get the overlapping area you'll need to get the bounds of each object relative to their common parent, then use the intersection function.  Using the stage is probably easiest since it is parent to all display objects, and it will make it easy to work with the localToGlobal and globalToLocal functions.

Here's some example code to get you started.  Assuming sprite1 and sprite2 are overlapping and you want to draw the overlapping rectangle into sprite1:

```
var bounds1:Rectangle = sprite1.getBounds(stage);
var bounds2:Rectangle = sprite2.getBounds(stage);

var overlapping:Rectangle = bounds1.intersection(bounds2);
var localPoint:Point = sprite1.globalToLocal(new Point(overlapping.x, overlapping.y));

overlapping.x = localPoint.x;
overlapping.y = localPoint.y;

var shape:Shape = new Shape();
shape.graphics.beginFill(0xff0000);
shape.graphics.drawRect(overlapping.x, overlapping.y, overlapping.width, overlapping.height);
shape.graphics.endFill();
sprite1.addChild(shape);
```

Answer (score 1):

hittest to detect the object is a common way. 
The example below code is a change alpha value when hittest or not.
if you want Change the color of the object. you are set property in matrix colorTransform.
But, in general, in FlashGames `Pixel Perfect Collision Detection` rather than `hitTestObject` used. because it is much more accurate. more information about PPCD is Google it.

here is code: [HitTest_Object](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-b1fb31fb.html)

```
sun_mc.startDrag( true );

stage.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter );

function  onEnter( e: Event ): void
{
    if( sun_mc.hitTestObject( snowman_mc ) == true )
    {
        snowman_mc.alpha = 0.5;
    }
    else
    {
        snowman_mc.alpha = 1;
    } 
}
```

Comment: here you are making transparent the whole object, but i need to make transparent just a portion of that object or change the color of that hitted area, just a portion

Comment: So PPCD i think this is more close to what i need

Comment: i think, you must know about PPCD. Google it. AS3.0 Official API is no way what you needs.

Comment: When using the PPCD skills can get accurate hit area coordinates.

Comment: so what about the object.hitArea - property?, is the PPCD an built-in AS3 class?, looks like no...